# How to add prefix and suffix values for a column in spark dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

Input dataframe

```
    val ds = Seq((1,"play Framwork"),
  (2,"Spark framework"),
  (3,"spring framework")).toDF("id","subject")
```

Suppose my `prefix` value is **prefix** and `suffix` is **suffix** . Then i expect the following **DataFrame**

Expected dataframe

```
 val ds = Seq((1,"play Framwork",prefixplay Frameworksuffix),
  (2,"Spark framework",prefixSpark frameworksuffix),
  (3,"spring framework"),prefixspring frameworksuffix).toDF("id","subject",prefixsubjectsuffix)
```

So as you can see , i am expecting a new colunm to be created with name as `prefix+columnName+suffix` as **prefixsubjectsuffix** . Also the `values` of that column should be converted as my expected .

I am trying to use some `udf` to achieve this like as below

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
  val concatPrefixSuffixWithColumnValues=
udf((column:String,prefix:String,suffix:String)=>
prefix.concat(column).concat(suffix))
```

But when i use it through the following statement gives some compilation error

```
dataset.withColumn(s"$prefixsubject$suffix",concatPrefixSuffixWithColumnValues("subject",prefix,suffix))
```

So how can i achieve this . Any references ??